# How to get intersection of two realm Results<T> in swift

Tags: swift2, realm

I am new t realm I have 2 realm results, I get those results by performing filter on a table. Now I want the intersect of those results. we can not add object to realm results. is there a way to get the results intersect in realm

```
let results = realm.objects(Member).filter("firstName BEGINSWITH[c] '\(searchText)' OR lastName BEGINSWITH[c] '\(searchText)' OR idenedi BEGINSWITH[c] '\(searchText)'")

let results1 = realm.objects(Member).filter("firstName BEGINSWITH[c] '\(searchText1)' OR lastName BEGINSWITH[c] '\(searchText1)' OR idenedi BEGINSWITH[c] '\(searchText)'")
```

How can I get intersect of results and results1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
let set = Set(results.map { $0 })
let set1 = Set(results1.map { $0 })
let intersect = set.intersect(set1)
```

But beware that this solution might not perform as fast as you want if you have many objects in your results.